Filtrar un texto en bash
Buenas yo tengo esta salida que la quiero guardar en un texto.txt.
Ultralytics YOLOv8.2.58  Python-3.12.3 torch-2.3.1+cpu CPU (12th Gen Intel Core(TM) i9-12900K)
YOLOv8l summary (fused): 268 layers, 43,668,288 parameters, 0 gradients, 165.2 GFLOPs

...
941b3d562238e25c3e65ca8c2483c9c8ec3ba2040d9a772eb59136b0daec112b.jpg: 640x480 1 sports ball, 2903.0ms
c1da45417742f9de0b118ff02e7657e85d66c19ed3f8287b634466c8277c740a.jpg: 640x448 1 person, 2846.4ms
d046fe89912ad238e124041960f1e41259ddfa16cd0945c702c286b54b8cce2c.jpg: 640x480 (no detections), 2895.1ms
...

Speed: 1.8ms preprocess, 2881.5ms inference, 1.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 480)

yo ando con este código

cut -d ' ' -f1,3- | tr -s '\n' | tail -n +3 | head -n -1 | sed -e 's/, \S*$//'|tr -d '(,)'  > texto.txt

eso me devuelve esto:
...
941b3d562238e25c3e65ca8c2483c9c8ec3ba2040d9a772eb59136b0daec112b.jpg: 1 sports ball
c1da45417742f9de0b118ff02e7657e85d66c19ed3f8287b634466c8277c740a.jpg: 1 person
d046fe89912ad238e124041960f1e41259ddfa16cd0945c702c286b54b8cce2c.jpg: no detections
...

Si se puede mejorar el código solamente, gracias!

Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so]. El formato del sitio es de preguntas y respuestas, por lo tanto, borra la palabra "solucionado" del título y pon como respuesta qué ha respondido a tu pregunta, en base a [answer]. Por último, acepta tu respuesta luego de haber transcurrido el tiempo mínimo (48 horas).

grep "\.jpg" input |  sed -e 's/, \S*$//'|tr -d '(,)'> texto.txt

La parte de grep ".jpg" me sirvio, con eso pude dejar de usar "tr -s '\n' | tail -n +3 | head -n -1", Gracias!

Hasta donde entiendo tu output, lo que buscas solo son los nombres de los .jpg con lo que detectó ultralytics en los archivos.
Mi primera sugerencia es que busques dentro de la propia librería los tipos de formato de salida que te pueda dar.
La segunda es que uses Perl con una regex:
$ perl -lne '/(^\w+?\.jpg: )\d+x\d+ (.*?(?=,))/ && print $1, $2' archivo

Que te da lo que buscas:
941b3d562238e25c3e65ca8c2483c9c8ec3ba2040d9a772eb59136b0daec112b.jpg: 1 sports ball
c1da45417742f9de0b118ff02e7657e85d66c19ed3f8287b634466c8277c740a.jpg: 1 person
d046fe89912ad238e124041960f1e41259ddfa16cd0945c702c286b54b8cce2c.jpg: (no detections)

La regex se descompone en 3 partes:

(^\w+?\.jpg: ) -> Lo que empiece de forma alfanumerica, tenga la extenci´no .jpg, luego tenga dos puntos y un espacio y ponlo en el grupo 1
\d+x\d+  -> Lo que sea de la forma {numero}x{numero}
(.*?(?=,)) -> Cualquier caracter antes de una coma ponlo en el grupo 2

Y con print $1, $2, lo único que hacemos es imprimir los grupos 1 y 2
